# Can a USB pen/hard drive be used with a Logitech Revue?

Tags: hardware, usb-peripherals, logitech-revue

Can the Logitech Revue play videos and display images from a USB pen/hard drive?

What are the hardware specifications of the Logitech Revue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this forum post](http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Revue/Revue-USB-Storage-Device-is-the-Revue-a-good-HTPC/td-p/558756), I would say yes.  It wouldn't make sense for it to support external harddrives without supporting simpler USB keys.

As for specs, Google returns many results.  [Endgadget has an overview](http://www.engadget.com/2010/10/25/logitech-revue-with-google-tv-torn-down-netbook-specs-found-wit/), with a link to [more details](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Logitech-Revue-Teardown/3788/1).